# How to append query params in URL in case of input forward?

Tags: java, jsp, url, parameters, struts

I am having trouble in maintaining the value of the query params which was sent in URL and lost during input forward due to validation error.

I have a link link this

```
<a href="/somelink/testpage?param1=value1&param2=value2" id="test">Test</a>
```

Clicking this link opens a new page which has a form with two hidden fields (which takes the value from these params). This page has two buttons <kbd>save</kbd> and <kbd>cancel</kbd>. My problem is

1. I click the link, the input page corresponding to this action is `test.jsp`. This renders the page.(ex the URL is `https:host/somelink/testpage?param1=value1&param2=value2`).
2. I fill the form and click Save button which submits the form. In the Action class I get the params and set in request and do validation . Due to validation error, control goes to input page (but without query params in url). Now the input page has the error message and the URL is `https:host/somelink/testpage`
3. Now in the `test.jsp`, from the request the hidden fields  in form are filled.
4. The error is shown in the input page. Now if I click the save button again control goes to the Action class with form being submitted. In this case I can access those params (as form is submitted)
5. But there is a case where  in the input page with error, if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> from address bar the request will go to action class (Remember when forward was done to the input page, the query params are not set in url, so now if request is sent there is no way to get the value of the param as its not in url and the form is not submitted.)

Is there any way I can maintain the value of the params? I am not able to append it to URL as its a input forward. Only way I found to retain the values of params is add in session and get from session. But I am not sure if its advisable.

Comment: The action form (or action if Struts 2) should have properties for those fields. The form should use normal Struts form tags for the hidden fields. Done.

Comment: Yes I use Struts form tags. But the fields are not part of the action form.

Comment: (E.g., if it *did*, you wouldn't have to do anything special to get the values filled back in, you wouldn't have to manipulate the URL, etc.)

Comment: My understanding is even though if I have them in the Action Form, only when the form is submitted I can get the value in Action class right?

Comment: When else would you need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form you didn't pass parameters in the url. To make it working you should include parameters in the `action` attribute of the form tag.

Like

```
<html:form action="/somelink/testpage?param1=value1&param2=value2">
```

or submit the form without parameters in the URL, but to pass parameters you need to add
`html:hidden` fields to the form, that will hold the values.

Comment: Yes I Use struts form tag, the hidden fields have the value that was set in request in the Action class, the only problem is in case of a request to the specified action without submitting the form. 
Thank you adding the params to the action attribute helps me.

Comment: This solution will work for my problem however in my application action attribute is dynamically generated so its not simple for me to change the code that generates it. I was wondering if there was any possibility of changing the path of the input page.

Comment: @SpreeTheGr8 You could change it like you want, `request.setAttribute("myUrl","/somelink/testpage?param1=value1&param2=value2"); <html:form action=${myUrl}>`.

Comment: We extend the struts tags and have our additional attributes, so the form tag appends few other context specific information to the url. So  in order to change the url I have to introduce an attribute to the form tag which takes the param value and make the FormTag.java generate the url with these params.

Comment: The value comes to the action attribute, and you should not modify this part, anyway you could get params there.

Comment: Even though we add context specific path info to the action attribute in FormTag we do check for query params already existing in the form but there is a mistake in that and so I am always losing those params.

Comment: is it valid or good procedure to add params in action in case of post method?